# javascript 'or' statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

```
var NavAxis='yx';
var url1 = 'file:///C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Senior%20Project/index.html#/page4'
var url2 = 'file:///C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/Senior%20Project/index.html#/page5'   

if(location.href == (url1 || url2)){
      NavAxis='xy';
}else{
       NavAxis='yx';
}
```

Why doesn't this work? I want it to be so that if the URL is either of those stated NavAxis changes to 'xy'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you really want is:

```
if ( location.href === url1 || location.href === url2 )
```

What you wrote will evaluate the inner parentheses first:  `(url1 || url2)`. That will evaluate to `url1` as long as `url1` is truthy (which it is in your code).

So your condition will only be true if `location.href` is equal to `url1` but not `url2`.

Answer (score 6):

#### How JavaScript OR works:

```
true || true   // true;
true || false  // true;
false || false // false;
0 || true      // 0 will translate to boolean because other side is boolean and it returns true
1 || 3         // no translation, returns 1
undefined || 2 // undefined will translated to boolean false. returns 2
null || "wow"  // "wow"
```

This is how you should this:

```
if(location.href == url1 || location.href == url2){
    NavAxis='xy';
}else{
   NavAxis='yx';
}
```

This works for two or three checks, but what if you had 10 urls?

This is a better approach using [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method that works for multiple item checks:

```
if([url1, url2, url3].indexOf(location.href) != -1 ){
        NavAxis='xy';
    }else{
       NavAxis='yx';
    }
```

Comment: To answer the question, the reason the original code doesn't work is that `(url1 || url2)` will evaluate to `true`, and `location.href` will also evaluate to `true`, giving you `if (true == true)`.

Comment: @djlumley that is incorrect, `url1 || url2` will evaluate to `url1` and `location.href` will evaluate to another string, these two strings are then compared for equality, giving you `if( "some_url" == url1)`.

Comment: Note that `Array.indexOf()` is not available in older versions of (stupid) IE.

Comment: @tobyodavies You're right, need a coffee and to think before typing~

Comment: @SalmanA Solution for older browsers is just [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)

Answer (score 5):

`url1 || url2` will evaluate to `file:///...#/page4` (i.e. `url1`). So essentially, you are comparing `location.href` with `url1` all the time. To compare with either, try:

```
if (location.href == url1 || location.href == url2)
```